Compose Image "wrap_content"
I have this Composable and I want the Image to take all the horizontal space and adapt the size vertically to not either cut or change the shape of the image.
I didn't find any way to achieve this so I had to set a fixed height for the box and use ContentScale.Crop.
I tried to use Intrinsic modifier but without result, it doesn't work as the wrap_content used for XML layout.
This is the UI I'm trying to achieve but I want the height not to be fixed.

private fun DrawCoverForPhone(cover: Cover?) {
val context = LocalContext.current
val painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
    ImageRequest.Builder(context)
        .data(data = cover?.large)
        .crossfade(true)
        .error(context.logoMarkPlaceholder())
        .build()
)
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .height(140.dp)
        .background(Colors.neutral50)
        .clip(
            RoundedCornerShape(
                topEnd = 8.dp,
                topStart = 8.dp,
                bottomStart = 0.dp,
                bottomEnd = 0.dp
            )
        )
) {
    if (painter.state is AsyncImagePainter.State.Error) {
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(vertical = Theme.dimensions.spacingMedium)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .fillMaxHeight(),
            painter = painter,
            contentDescription = null,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Fit
        )
    } else {
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .fillMaxHeight(),
            painter = painter,
            contentDescription = null,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
        )
    }
}


You can try:
private fun DrawCoverForPhone(cover: Cover?) {
val context = LocalContext.current
val painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
    ImageRequest.Builder(context)
        .data(data = cover?.large)
        .crossfade(true)
        .error(context.logoMarkPlaceholder())
        .build()
)
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(Colors.neutral50)
        .clip(
            RoundedCornerShape(
                topEnd = 8.dp,
                topStart = 8.dp,
                bottomStart = 0.dp,
                bottomEnd = 0.dp
            )
        )
) {
    if (painter.state is AsyncImagePainter.State.Error) {
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(vertical = Theme.dimensions.spacingMedium)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .fillMaxHeight(),
            painter = painter,
            contentDescription = null,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Fit
        )
    } else if (painter.state is AsyncImagePainter.State.Success) {
        val ratioModifier = painter.state.painter.intrinsicSize.let { intrinsicSize ->
                    Modifier.aspectRatio(intrinsicSize.width / intrinsicSize.height)
                }
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .then(ratioModifier),
            painter = painter,
            contentDescription = null,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
        )
    }
}

Explanation:
First, .height(140.dp) is removed from Box so that it will take size of it's children & then, .fillMaxHeight() is replaced with .then(ratioModifier) which has .aspectRatio(ratio) applied for the Image.
Important:
Here, you need to calculate the ratio from the loaded image's dimensions so that the Image will be as wide as possible & also not cutting/cropping the actual image.
Example:
val width = 200F
val height = 100F
val ratio = width / height

Hope this works.

My idea was to avoid calculation, anyway I will try your suggestion

You need the calculations at your end so as your UI looks nice & same on every screen size & also to show entire image without cropping or changing the original aspect ratio.
PS: Let me know if my answer works
